# check if variable is not empty in perl

Tags: perl

I am calling a subroutine in main() like below:

sendMail($opts, $test)

I want to call this subroutine only if the $test is not empty.

Can some please help me with the the if condition that I need to mention in the above line to check the same.

Thanks

Comment: This could work ```sendMail($opts, $test) if($test);```

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you mean by "empty".

If you're looking for a true or false value then just test the variable itself:

```
sendMail($opts, $test) if $test;
```

If you're looking for a string that isn't empty, then test the length of the variable:

```
sendMail($opts, $test) if length $test;
```

If you're looking for a variable that contains any value, then check with `defined()`:

```
sendMail($opts, $test) if defined $test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$test` is a string, not an array reference or something:

```
if (length $test) {
    sendMail($opts, $test);
}
```